# Mass Geocoding Requests for Germany?

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, germany

To say it upfront: This is a question that [has already come up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781915/whats-the-easiest-way-to-do-a-one-time-mass-geocode-580-000-addresses) before in Stack Overflow but did not provide a manageable and legal solution for my problem (see below).

I have a database (in STATA format) of around **1,3 million addresses in Germany** with street name, house number, zip code and city stored separately in different variables.
For each of those I need the longitude and latitude which I then want to store in a (local) database and use later on in a statistical analysis (in the context of a research project). Note that this is a one-time request for each of those addresses!

Essentially, this poses four requirements on the service to be used:

1. It needs to cover Germany (in particular its rural areas)
2. It needs to be *sufficiently exact*, i.e. I am willing to take the imprecision of around 100m relative to the object placed at the corresponding address, preferably less of course
3. My usage needs to comply with the terms of services
4. It should be for free or the price should be reasonable / It should take a reasonable time to obtain the data (<= 4 weeks)

Before I look into licenses for commercial usage, I want to get an overview of free / reasonable priced services. Seen against this background, the third condition seems to rule out the big players like Google and Yahoo since they do not allow to store the data (see also discussion in GIS SE at [Geocode address once in google maps, save in database, read geocoded result from there on](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27194)).

I checked with an employee of Google Germany who claimed they would charge 10,000 EUR (which appears to be way too high, though).

Do any services come to your mind that suit those requirements?
If so, do program codes exists to collect and store the data?

I have also [raised this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785482/geocoding-mutiple-german-addresses) in Stack Overflow where it was put on hold. Since I did not find restrictions for this kind of "preference question" for the GIS Q&A section, I am posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Geocode.xyz is free and covers Germany: http://geocode.xyz/DE (both forward and reverse geocoding)

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".